# ASMX can't set known type attributes

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, asmx

Im working on ASMX service that allows me to work with databases and their tables. The schema looks like this

```
[DataContract]
public class DataBase
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<Table> Tables { get; set; }
...
}

[DataContract]
public class Table
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Column> Columns { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<List<object>> Data { get; set; }
...
}

[DataContract]
public class Column
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
   [ DataMember]
    public string Type { get; set; }
...
}
```

"Data" field is meant to keep a table of all values of different types. The problem is - i have to work with a few of custom types:

```
public class Email
{
    [DataMember]
    public string address { get; set; }
...
}

public class Strings : List<string>
{
    public Strings(IEnumerable<string> collection) : base(collection) { }
...
}
```

And the problem is that web service does not create references to these types. I do not use them in methods explicitly, but store in table. Using KnownType and DataContract did not help me, and when i created same classes in a client app, i have exceptions. Please, help?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it: basically i created dummy methods that returned object of nedded types, deleted the method references from client app and it worked.